# Can't compiler sass on wsl ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sass, compilation

i have wls with ubuntu 20.04 and y try to compiler sass with the npm sass package but i got this error when i use

```
sass --trace --watch /sass/main.sass:/css/main.css --style=compressed
```

> > > Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > 9: from /usr/bin/sass:8:in `<main>' 8: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/exec/base.rb:18:in` parse!'
> > > 7: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/exec/base.rb:50:in `parse' 6: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:51:in` process_result'
> > > 5: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:354:in `watch_or_update' 4: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/plugin.rb:109:in` method_missing'
> > > 3: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:319:in `watch' 2: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:380:in` create_listener'
> > > 1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require' /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in` require': cannot load such file -- sass-listen (LoadError)

Answer (score -1):

I resolve installing ruby and sass-listen

Comment: How did you install sass-listen ? 'sudo apt-get install sass-listen' replies with Unable to locate package sass-listen.